# How to reference a Form's ModelMutiplechoiceField to a foreignKey in Django?

Tags: django

Consider my model like this:

```
class Major(models.Model):
    major_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', null=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.major_name

class Minor(models.Model):
    major_name = models.ForeignKey(Major, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    minor_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', null=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.minor_name
```

Then with this form:

```
class PreferredMinorForm(forms.Form):
    preferred_minor= forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Minor.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required=False
    )
```

I can loop through minor to be displayed on template. But how do I loop through minor that is under major?

Currently, my code looks like this:

view:

```
minor = PreferredMinorForm()
context['minor_list'] = minor
context['major_list'] = Major.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('id')
```

template:

```
{% for major in major_list %}
    {{major}}                    
    {% for minor in minor_list %}
        # How to if statement here?
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If I test minor, I got this:

```
<li><label for="id_minor_45"><input type="checkbox" name="minor" value="46" id="id_minor_45">DATA</label></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question

> how do I loop through minor that is under major?

You can access items of the related model using the "_set" syntax. This can be used for [accessing a collection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#accessing-method-calls) of related objects on a foreign key. In your template you can access it like this.

```
{% for major in major_list %}
    {{ major }}                    
    {% for minor in major.minor_set.all %}
        {{ minor }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This will give you the related objects, but it's not going to give the form html. You could also look at accessing [related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) in the queryset in the form.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of me using my form if I loop i through set.

Comment: Could try accessing [value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.value) of the form field to test in an if condition against the ids of the minor_set. Placing the form in a loop makes it difficult to filter the queryset.